# Monitoring command prompt executed programs with Fiddler2

Tags: web-services, windows-7, dos, fiddler

I am currently experimenting with using Fiddler 2 to monitor web service requests. I would like to know if it is possible to pick up the sessions from a program run via the command prompt in Windows 7. I have tried configuring the command prompt to use the local host proxy using the following:

netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8888

This doesn't seem to have made a difference though since running the program (a simple sample from the Axis2C install which communicates with a Yahoo web service) still produces no session in Fiddler. I would appreciate any help anyone can give on setting this up to work.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp explains how to hook various HTTP stacks to Fiddler. It sounds like you've ruled out WinINET and WinHTTP; you should ask the maintainers of "Axis2C" what network stack it uses.